# linux terminal error while installing

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netattack2.py", line 47, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/all.py", line 10, in <module>`dtytyty`
    from .config import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/config.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .data import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/data.py", line 184, in <module>
    TCP_SERVICES,UDP_SERVICES=load_services("/etc/services")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/data.py", line 109, in load_services
    f=open(filename, errors='ignore')
TypeError: 'errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: does anyone knows how to fix

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at these guidelines, [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `errors=` is from a python **3** `open` statement, you are clearly trying to run python 3 code on python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errors=` is from a python 3 `open` statement, you are clearly trying to run python 3 code on python 2.

We can't say *how* you got the wrong version of `scapy` because you don't show how you installed it.

Your options are to either install the python 2 version of scapy (probably the easiest) or to upgrade to python 3.

Answer (score 0):

From the error mentioned, it seems you are trying to install scapy(packet manipulator). Since it's not clear on what you did and u got such an error, try using below mentioned method to install scapy first,

```
pip install scapy
```

for your, 'errors' is an invalid argument, try giving encoding as an argument as well. like,

```
file=open(filename, encoding='latin-1', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Giving the `encoding` argument is not an option since the OP is running python 2.7 (look at the filename path and the **python 2.7** tag on the question).